# Lagrange error for vector-valued linear interpolation?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, interpolation

If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is a $C^2$ function, and $p_1(x)$ is the linear interpolation of $f(x)$ between $a$ and $b$, then as far as I know, we get the following Lagrange form of the error between $f$ and $p_1$:

- For all $x\in[a,b]$, we have $f(x)-p_1(x)=\frac12 f''(\zeta_x) (x-a)(x-b)$ for some $\zeta_x\in[a,b]$.

If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ instead, then what is the closest analogue to this statement that we can get?

Surely an equality of $\mathbb R^2$ vectors is too much to hope for? Is the best we can do something like this:

- For all $x\in[a,b]$, we have $\|f(x)-p_1(x)\|\leq\frac12 \|f''(\zeta_x)\| (x-a)(x-b)$ for some $\zeta_x\in[a,b]$.

Is that even true? If so, is there an easy proof or a standard reference that develops it?

Also, what conditions are there on the norm $\|\cdot\|$ to get this statement? Does it have to be an inner-product norm?

For comparison, there's a similar statement for a vector-valued mean value theorem in Rudin, *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*, Theorem 5.19, which is cited in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Mean_value_theorem&oldid=1187347181#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).

Comment: Maybe you can use a contour integral to express the remainder as shown in the following link in the 1d case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial#Remainder_in_Lagrange_interpolation_formula. A proof in the 1 d case (that I did not verify) is given here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513587/contour-integral-representation-of-lagrange-interpolating-formula. Maybe that proof can be used component wise on $f$. Then one might try to find an inequality for the norm of the remainder expressed as a vector valued integral.